# Drawing an X in 2D array

Tags: python

I am currently working out a python project. Below is everything that I know/ was able to derive from the given problem. I am struggling with syntax, however.

Draw an X in a 2D grid.

Given a 2D grid (ie. a nested list of strings), replace specific squares
to form an "X" (the capital X) from corner to corner, using character in sign.

```
Arguments:
    grid (list): A nested list of size N by N, filled with spaces (" ").
        Assume N is positive and odd.
    sign (char): A typographic character with which to fill the X

Returns:
    list: The modified nested list with a large X that goes from corner to corner.

Examples:

    Note that although I print out each row by itself for clarity, the
    return value should be a nested list.

    >>> grid = [ \
            [" ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " "], \
        ]
    >>> result = mark_the_spot(grid, 'X')
    >>> for row in result:
    ...     print(row)
    ...
    ['X', ' ', 'X']
    [' ', 'X', ' ']
    ['X', ' ', 'X']

    >>> grid = [ \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
            [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], \
        ]
    >>> result = mark_the_spot(grid, '#')
    >>> for row in result:
    ...     print(row)
    ...
    ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#']
    [' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ']
    [' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ']
    [' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ']
    [' ', ' ', '#', ' ', '#', ' ', ' ']
    [' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#', ' ']
    ['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#']
```

Comment: And what's your question? If the question is "can you do it for me?", it's not a valid question here.

Comment: What syntax are you struggling with? Where is the code for `mark_the_spot()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single loop, calculating the positions to set on each iteration.

```py
def mark_the_spot(grid, ch):
    import copy
    result = copy.deepcopy(grid)
    n = len(grid)
    for i in range(n):
        result[i][i] = result[i][n - i - 1] = ch
    return result
```